# okhttp string problem if using string in .url

Tags: java, string, api, url, okhttp

I'm using API from a website and it needs two strings
String one: modelId
String two: inferenceId
both of them are equal to value

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url("https://api.leapml.dev/api/v1/images/models/"+modelId+"/inferences/"+inferenceId)
                        .get()
                        .addHeader("accept", "application/json")
                        .addHeader("authorization", "Bearer *secret word here*")
                        .build();
                
                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

My issue is in Example: A

```
.uri("https://api.leapml.dev/api/v1/images/models/"+modelId+"/inferences/"+inferenceId)
```

if I added both modelId string and inferenceId string the the above code, the API doesn't work correctly

but if I add the text directly there like in below, everything works great
Example: B

```
.url("https://api.leapml.dev/api/v1/images/models/1285ded4-b11b-4993-a491-d87cdfe6310c/inferences/3f9f5c8d-320f-4afc-85c4-454522118c16")
```

Both of the above gives me the EXACT same result if I got the value of request.url(); but the API gets faulty with the example A
But works fine with example B

Log of Example A (faulty one)

> I/System.out: Second Step:
> {"id":"f9828985-af41-46be-b8bc-ef81504b4a87","state":"queued","prompt":"cow","seed":4523184,"width":1024,"height":1024,"numberOfImages":1,"steps":50,"weightsId":"8b1b897c-d66d-45a6-b8d7-8e32421d02cf","workspaceId":"d76af992-7c3e-4b1a-bc72-46b27de7c377","createdAt":"2023-02-01T09:56:42.255006+00:00","images":[],"modelId":"8b1b897c-d66d-45a6-b8d7-8e32421d02cf"}

Log with Example B (Working perfect)

> I/System.out: Second Step:
> {"id":"3f9f5c8d-320f-4afc-85c4-454522118c16","state":"finished","prompt":"cow","seed":4523184,"width":512,"height":512,"numberOfImages":1,"steps":50,"weightsId":"1285ded4-b11b-4993-a491-d87cdfe6310c","workspaceId":"d76af992-7c3e-4b1a-bc72-46b27de7c377","createdAt":"2023-02-01T08:54:31.244159+00:00","images":[{"id":"f6518aea-f2a3-47ac-b9ff-81ca8c996206","uri":"https://dreamtrain.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/image-gen-3f9f5c8d-320f-4afc-85c4-454522118c16/generated_images/0.png","createdAt":"2023-02-01
> 08:54:42.784652+00"}],"modelId":"1285ded4-b11b-4993-a491-d87cdfe6310c"}

As you can see Example B has "uri" image link and that's what i need.

I tried many things but it seemed like nothing help.

Comment: Try printing the built url string to see what goes wrong

Comment: I printed request.url() on both examples gives me same output (EXACTLY).
But the API responds different.

Comment: @MazenH., as a note, the `modelId` of Example A is different from the `modelId` of Example B.  You're using one which starts with "8b1b897c" in Example A, and one that starts with "1285ded4" in Example B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue and the solution,
The API I'm using (Leapml) takes about 10 seconds to generate me the image link. So if I let the thread sleep for 11 seconds everything works just great

Thanks for everyone tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
String url = "https://api.leapml.dev/api/v1/images/models/"+modelId+"/inferences/"+inferenceId;

System.out.println(url); // This should be equal to "https://api.leapml.dev/api/v1/images/models/1285ded4-b11b-4993-a491-d87cdfe6310c/inferences/3f9f5c8d-320f-4afc-85c4-454522118c16"

// Use the variable as argument
.url(url);
```

If this still not work. Please provide the logs.

Comment: Nope, unfortunately it didn't work too.
API received data and didn't return error but returned missing data (the issue) 
I added logs on the post

Answer (score 0):

It seems your are trying to add binary data to the string. Check whether your are getting the actual string which you need.

Comment: I'm getting the EXACT same result when I print request.url on both examples.

Comment: Both System.out.print.ln();

https://api.leapml.dev/api/v1/images/models/8b1b897c-d66d-45a6-b8d7-8e32421d02cf/inferences/bf76a04b-f5e9-4eb3-897e-737039071c65
https://api.leapml.dev/api/v1/images/models/8b1b897c-d66d-45a6-b8d7-8e32421d02cf/inferences/bf76a04b-f5e9-4eb3-897e-737039071c65